# How to properly use group access and chgrp?

Tags: linux, permissions, chown

I attempting to deploy files to a remote server using SSH.

My username `joe` is a member of the group `www`.

I am SSH'ing in as joe, and creating a new folder (let's call it `test`).  The parent folder's owners are `root:www`.  When I issue the `mkdir /parent/test` command over ssh, the owners for the new directory are `joe:joe`.  I'd like the group to be set to `www`.

If I attempt to issue the command `chgrp www /parent/test`, I get a permission denied error.
Ultimately, I don't care about who the owner of the file is, although if the file's owners were `www:www` that would be nice. I just want to be able to create files on the remote server, while logging in as my username, and then change the group of the files to `www`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `newgrp` before using `mkdir` to "log in" to a new group

```
mymachine$ ssh joe@remotemachine
remotemachine$ newgrp www
remotemachine$ mkdir /parent/test
```

Comment: Actually, ran into a slight problem.  Your answer works when using an interactive shell, but not over ssh.  `ssh joe@remotemachine newgrp www` will not work.  The `sg` command will work though, `ssh joe@remotemachine "sg www \"mkdir /parent/test\""`.

Comment: @Jon : very true. `newgrp` sets your group ID for the current session, until you log out or issue another newgrp, while `sg` runs a single command with the given group.